# how to fix issue with youtube embed video fullscreen button not showing up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

Below is my embed code. The full screen button doesn't show up at the width of 305 pixels. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<iframe width="305" height="200" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/HMUDVMiITOU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjrt81L0/)

Comment: can you just make it wider? it's like one of those questions about where i put my luggage on a motorcycle...

Comment: i have responsive design so it does work fine when using desktop browser but on mobile browser the video shows up but not the full screen button

Comment: if you are looking for a responsive way. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27015413/3448527

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with the same problem and for me the key was allowfullscreen="1" as an attribute in the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

use this one for the fullscreen button:

```
<object width="305" height="200">
  <param
    name="movie"
    value="http://www.youtube.com/v/HMUDVMiITOU">
  </param>
  <param
    name="allowscriptaccess"
    value="always">
  </param>
  <param
    name="allowFullScreen"
    value="true">
  </param>
  <embed
    src="http://www.youtube.com/v/HMUDVMiITOU"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    allowscriptaccess="always"
    allowfullscreen="true"
    width="305"
    height="200">
  </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: im trying to use html5 not flash i just saw in this example http://nthitz.github.io/turndownforwhatjs/ they did it im not sure how